# Regarding min_period in corr() function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, correlation

I am trying to create a corr matrix. This is regarding the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) on `min_period`. So what i understand is `min_period` is the number of days for which the correlation is calculated on? So for example

```
corr = df['Close'].corr(method= 'pearson', min_periods=10)
```

This would give me the correlation between 2 pairs as calculated on shifting 10 days basis? Please let me know if i understand it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you need at least 10 valid pairs. Othwerwise it will be `np.nan`. Documentation states:

> Minimum number of observations required per pair of columns to have a valid result. Currently only available for Pearson and Spearman correlation.